# Blank screen after login ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: authentication, ubuntu-16.04

I got Blank screen while login with correct id and password. 
Tried the following solution, still blank screen.

[Ubuntu 16.04 + Nvidia Driver = Blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760374/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-driver-blank-screen)

Answer (score 8):

Maybe the probleme is already solved but it's will be good to share the solution.
I hade the same problem and I found the solution here :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/779595/ubuntu-16-04-lts-black-screen-after-login
and here :
https://seravo.fi/2015/fixing-black-screen-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

had a nearly identical problem a few months ago. Switching into a console from the LightDM login screen (Ctrl-Alt-F1), logging in with administrative username and password, and entering the following commands resolved the issue:

sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
sudo service lightdm restart

Ctrl+Alt+F7 is for graphic login mode.

First login with the command line and run "**sudo apt-get update**" also for that you required internet connectivity. after that reboot system and go with recovery mode for repairing broken dpkg packages.

also find this link for exact solution: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2363945

Comment: Thanks pragya18nsit. This fixed my issue